# How to communicate between Python3 and JavaScript via sockets

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, sockets, websocket

I just set up a small TCP-socket server in python3, which waits for a connection, sends a small encoded text and waits for data from the client.

Python-Code:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 20000))

sock.listen(5)

while True:
    Client, address = sock.accept()
    Client.send("ping".encode())
    print(Client.recv(1024).decode())  # Here I want to receive data from the client
    Client.close()
```

At the end, there should be a browser interface which can communicate with the python backend with JQuery or just something that receive and send **(With data!)** sockets.

Thank you :D

**EDIT**:

Forgot to say that I can receive the text in a browser, I just need to know how to send data back.

Comment: Take a look at this article, they have very good examples with python3 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/

Comment: In short: Browsers cannot speak generic TCP sockets, they can do HTTP and they can do WebSockets (which is different from plain TCP sockets). Longer: To provide the functionality your server side backend needs to speak HTTP and maybe WebSocket protocol. Your client side code must implement the connectivity using Ajax and/or WebSockets. All of this is not trivial, which makes the question too broad in my opinion. I recommend that you start with something simpler by using existing servers and frameworks instead of trying to implement everything from scratch.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay, Got that! I'll rewrite the backend as a HTTP-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to connect to a NodeJS javascript environment then you should take a look at this native package
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netsocket

if you need to connect to a browser javascript environment then you should take a look at WebSockets

- Python: [https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#:~:text=websockets%20is%20a%20library%20for,an%20elegant%20coroutine%2Dbased%20API](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#:%7E:text=websockets%20is%20a%20library%20for,an%20elegant%20coroutine%2Dbased%20API).
- Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API