# Constantly sending data over flask to javascript in the front-end

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server, get

I'm building a web app that tracks a bicyclists' trips. Therefore, I need a constant transmission of lat/lng data to the javascript front-end to change the location of the marker on the map.
Would it be better to infinitely transfer this from the flask app-side or, is it possible to write a thread in javascript to do the same?

I have tried setting up multiprocessing on the python as mentioned in another answer, however, I need to return the value for the GET request (ajax) from the javascript side to work. For instance, this is one of my working get requests:

```
@app.route('/nearby')
def nearby():
    return GeoHandler.nearbyPlaces(GeoHandler, geodata.latlng[0], geodata.latlng[1])
```

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70729991/9038475)?

Comment: Take a look at sockets or [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: you heard of websocket?

Comment: Now I have, sorry I'm new to this. Thanks for the help.